# Loop a jQuery Animaton, upon completion, over and over?

Tags: jquery, loops, callback, jquery-animate

I am creating a site that needs an old-school CRT effect. I've got my tv static working nicely, but I needed a thick distortion bar to move up and down.

For this, I made a div at 100% width, 200px tall, that I wanted to start at the top of the page, move down, and upon hitting the bottom, zip back to the top, then start all over.

I have it working up until the looping part. It moves down, resets to the top, and then I want the function of the animation to repeat itself.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //vars
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var lineHeight = $('#bar').height();
var desiredBottom = windowHeight - lineHeight;
var newPosition = desiredBottom;
var moving = $('#bar');

animate_loop = function()
{
//FUNCTION ACTIONS
moving.animate({top:newPosition},
{
    duration: 2000,
    complete: function() 
    //function on completion - reset to top
    {
        $('#bar').animate({top:0},100);

    }


});

}//end of animate_loop = function()

animate_loop();

});// end of document ready
```

My bar moves down in the time I set it to animate for, it zips back up to the top flawlessly, but then....nothing. I tried a few methods before this, but then I saw an animation loop thread here that was laid out in this exact same way. Can someone point out why my animation will not loop when I try to execute "animate_loop();" near the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the inbuilt function call in [**.animate()**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) when the animation is complete. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //vars
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var lineHeight = $('#bar').height();
    var desiredBottom = windowHeight - lineHeight;
    var newPosition = desiredBottom;
    var moving = $('#bar');
    animate_loop = function () {
        //FUNCTION ACTIONS
        moving.animate({
            top: newPosition
        }, {
            duration: 2000,
            complete: function ()
            //function on completion - reset to top
            {
                $('#bar').animate({
                    top: 0
                }, 100, animate_loop);
        }
        });
} //end of animate_loop = function()
animate_loop();
}); // end of document ready
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. I'd tried setInterval earlier but I might have mucked up the syntax because it was a dud when I tried. Works great now in the position replacing animate_loop();

Comment: Great! glad it was useful!

Comment: you should never mix `setTimeout` (or worse yet `setInterval`) to schedule animations _while_ they're running.  It's OK to run them interleaved, but never in parallel.

Comment: @Alnitak, true that setIntervall creates parallel runs, corrected that and added the `.animate()` inbuilt function call also. Thank you.

Comment: @Sergio IMHO, this code is unnecessarily verbose - the entire loop can be done in just four lines with _improved_ readability.

Comment: @Alnitak, I cannot delete an accepted answer. But I agree your solution is better and more elegant. I can make a CW of this answer and use your answer if you would like.

Comment: Leave it here, but you should delete the `setTimeout` stuff - it's completely wrong.  Not my downvote, BTW.

Comment: @DillonRobinson, after rich input from Alnitak, I would like you to consider accepting his answer since my idea from the beginning was not optimal and I think he has the best answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Omitting your document ready handler and configuration variables for the sake of clarity, the simplest option for the animation code itself is just a completion callback coupled with an *immediately invoked function expression*

```
(function loop() {
    moving.animate({top: newPosition}, 2000)
          .animate({top: 0}, 100, loop);
})();
```

This four line block of code will start itself automatically (i.e. no need for a seperate explicit invocation), creates no new variables (`loop` is only visible in the scope of itself) and uses no extra timers.

Answer (score 1):

```
animate_loop = function () {
    //FUNCTION ACTIONS
    moving.animate({ top: newPosition },{
        duration: 2000,
        complete: function () { //function on completion - reset to top
            $('#bar').animate({ top: 0 }, 100, function () {
                animate_loop(); // <--
            });
        }
    });
}
```

You just have to call it again at the end.

Comment: no need for the extra `function` wrapper - just pass `animate_loop` directly as the third parameter to `.animate`.